# How to pass parameters to nested controller in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a router like that:

```
app.get('/rest/userList', (req, res) => {

    UserList.find({}, (err, users) => {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

I would like to change it like this:

```
app.get('/rest/userList', getUsers);

function getUsers(req, res) { 
    UserList.find({}, createResponse);
}

function createResponse(err, users) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.send(users);
}
```

However; in createResponse function 'res' is undefined. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.bind()` to bind extra parameters to the callback:

```
app.get('/rest/userList', getUsers);

function getUsers(req, res) { 
    UserList.find({}, createResponse.bind(null, res));
}

function createResponse(res, err, users) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.send(users);
}
```

Comment: this is actually what I was try to reach for DRY purposes! thnx!

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/rest/userList', getUsers, createResponse);

function getUsers(req, res, next) { 
    UserList.find({}, function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            req.errr = err;
        } else {
            req.users = users;
        }

        next();
    });
}

function createResponse(req, res) {
    if (req.err) return res.send(req.err);
    return res.send(req.users);
}
```